# Passing R vector to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, r, vector

I am trying to pass the numeric vector from R to an array in PHP.

`index.php:`

```
<?php
    $n = 3;
    $out = array();

    exec("Rscript script.R $n", $out);

    $length = count($out);
    echo "length = ".$length."<br>";

    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        echo "out[$i] = ".$out[$i]
?>
```

`script.R:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

i <- as.numeric(commandArgs(TRUE))
print(i:10)
```

Output:

```
length = 1  
out[0] = [1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

As you can see from the above output, PHP is storing a R vector as a single element of an array. How do I store the individual elements of a R vector in PHP array?

Comment: you can do `$out=explode(' ',$out[0]);` after your exec statement to make it an actual array with actual elements in the right places.

Comment: @Dimi How do I get rid of empty values? The output I got after `explode` is: `out[0] = [1]out[1] = out[2] = 3out[3] = out[4] = 4out[5] = out[6] = 5out[7] = out[8] = 6out[9] = out[10] = 7out[11] = out[12] = 8out[13] = out[14] = 9out[15] = 10`
Also I don't want that initial `[1]`. Actual vector starts from `3`

Comment: you can use array_filter command to get rid of empty values. You can add your own filter to it which will remove values that you do not like.  Or just do `unset($out[0]);unset($out[1]);unset($out[2]);`

Comment: @Dimi Didn't work. The output I got is: `length = 9
out[0] = [1]
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/php-r/index.php on line 13
out[1] = out[2] = 3
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/php-r/index.php on line 13
out[3] = out[4] = 4
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/html/php-r/index.php on line 13
out[5] = out[6] = 5
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/php-r/index.php on line 13
out[7] = out[8] = 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at [php-r](https://github.com/kachkaev/php-r).

I changed my `index.php` as:

```
exec("Rscript my_script.R $n", $out);

$length = count($out);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
foreach (explode("\n", $out[$i]) as $row) {
    If (strpos($row, ']') !== false)
        $numbersAsStr = substr($row, strpos($row, ']') + 1); 
    else
        $numbersAsStr = $row;
    foreach (explode(' ', $numbersAsStr) as $potentialNumber)
        if ($potentialNumber !== '')
            array_push($result, 0 + $potentialNumber);
}
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(8) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(5) [3]=> int(6) [4]=> int(7) [5]=> int(8) [6]=> int(9) [7]=> int(10) }
```